# How to find character at byte offset in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with some (apparently) mangled serialized data in a MySQL database, after a conversion to UTF-8. When I try to unserialize them, I get the usual:

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 1481 of 255200 bytes [...]
```

However, given that this is a multi-byte string, I can't figure out how to find which character is at that byte offset. What I need is something like `substr()` but for bytes, instead of characters. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a `substr($str, 1481, 2);`, `substr($str, 1481, 3);` or `substr($str, 1481, 4);`. If it's an UTF-8 you'll find it in any of thos 3 substrings, because an UTF-8 char may take from 2 to 4 chars, depending on the first char.

I've had a lot of problems with this, so if you can't find what's going on with the encoding, answer again :-) I'll try to lend you a hand.

Good luck!

Edit: Don't forget to do a header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf8"); to watch the result properly.

Comment: Thanks! I marked this as accepted, because it's correct, although I still can't solve my problem with the encoding. The character I got was a greek ς but even after replacing all instances of ς with a latin s (just for testing, to see if that was actualyl the problem) the string still doesn't unserialize :( Any ideas?

Comment: `serialize()` is messy. If you are storing arrays and scalars only, i recommend you to use json_encode() rather than `serialize()`.

Comment: I agree but I didn't write (most of) the application and that's a huge change at this point.

Answer (score 0):

`substr` does work on bytes instead of characters. So this should return the 1481st byte:

```
substr($data, 1481, 1)
```